# accessing StageWebView via ANE

Tags: air, air-native-extension, stagewebview

I'd like to write an ANE that can access the native part of a [StageWebView](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html) (iOS's [UIWebView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)/Android's [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)).  This is so that I can call native webview methods that StageWebView doesn't provide (e.g., accessing cookies).

I'd like to think this is possible, but I'm not sure how to get started.

Comment: same here - any progress so far?

Comment: @mika sadly, no.  i suspect we'd have to walk the app's display hierarchy till we found a webview child (and hope that its the same one that the StageWebView is using).